# PSQL and TypeORM: Filter entity by relation, but don't filter relation

Tags: sql, filter, psql, typeorm

Imagine the following relationship:

```
Team --one-to-one--> Owner --many-to-many--> Role
```

The `Team` entity has a single `Owner` entity which has many `Role` entities.

I want to find teams that have an owner with a specific role.

I can successfully do this using the QueryBuilder:

```
const query = this.manager.createQueryBuilder()
  .select('team')
  .from(Team, 'team')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('team.owner', 'owner')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('owner.roles', 'roles'
  .where('roles.name IN (:...roles)', { roles })
  .getMany()
```

This correctly filters the teams based on the value of `roles` I provide.

However, the `team.owner.roles` value is *also* being filtered in the returned set. So if I search for a Team whose owner has the 'admin' role, any teams that match will all list *only* the 'admin' role in their roles - even if the original set contained more.

**How can I filter an entity based on a relational property, but still return the full set of the associated relational property**?

Comment: Seems like you may want an EXISTS subquery as opposed to a second  join, but it seems that is not currently implemented in TypeORM.See https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2815 for ideas

Comment: Thanks @Fred that's super helpful

Comment: Can you add entities for reproduction?